# How to generate CSR for SSL that works with Nginx & Apache?

Tags: apache, ssl, https, nginx, openssl

I want to generate the CSR file for requesting SSL (wildcard) certificate. This certificate and private key will be used on multiple machines with both Apache and Nginx.

RapitSSL states the following commands for the different setups:

- **Nginx**

  `$ openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout server.key -out server.csr`
- **Apache Mod SSL**

  `$ openssl genrsa -des3 -out <private key file name>.key 2048`
- **Apache-SSL**

  `$ openssl genrsa -des3 -out www.yourdomain-example.com.key 2048`

Is there a way to generate a CSR that works with both Apache and Nginx?

Comment: Voting to move to ServerFault, off-topic here.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. Please move to the appropriate forum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> - Apache Mod SSL
>
>   $ openssl genrsa -des3 -out < private key file name>.key 2048
> - Apache-SSL
>
>   $ openssl genrsa -des3 -out www.yourdomain-example.com.key 2048

These two are obviously the exact same command, with a different way of writing the example name. They just generate the key pair, you'd need an additional `req` command to generate a CSR too.

`genrsa` generates a key pair, and `req` generates a CSR. However, `req` can perform both operations at once when using `-newkey`.

See [OpenSSL `req` example documentation](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/req.html#EXAMPLES):

> Create a private key and then generate a certificate request from it:
>
> ```
> openssl genrsa -out key.pem 1024    
> openssl req -new -key key.pem -out req.pem
> ```
>
> The same but just using req:
>
> ```
> openssl req -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout key.pem -out req.pem
> ```

Comment: Many SSL certificate providers requires a 2048 bit key.

Comment: @ptz0n, sure that's just the sample documentation. Use 2048 where appropriate of course.

Answer (score 0):

> How to generate CSR for SSL that works with Nginx & Apache ...
>   Is there a way to generate a CSR that works with both Apache and Nginx?

A quick answer to the questions to clarify things... Nginx and Apache don't consume CSRs. They use certificates and private keys.

Perhaps you meant to say something about a self-signed certificate? If so, add the `-x509` option to the `openssl req` command. That creates a self signed certificate rather than a signing request.

There's a lot more to self-signed certificates (and server certificates in general). See, for example, [How to create a self-signed certificate with openssl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175812/how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-with-openssl/27931596#27931596)